# Why $⟨a│H'│a⟩=0$, when $H'$ has zero diagonal components?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

On 'David J.Griffiths, Introduction to Quantum Mechanics' Chapter 11.1.1 equations (11.16)
When $H'$ has zero diagonal component, $⟨a│H'│a⟩=0$

However, I think that there is needed conditon 'Components are pure imaginary' too.

For example,

$a=\left[\begin{matrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{matrix}\right]$

$H'=\left[\begin{matrix}
0&a&b\\a^*&0&c\\b^*&c^*&0
\end{matrix}\right]$

$⟨a│H'│a⟩=
\left[\begin{matrix}
x&y&z
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
0&a&b\\a^*&0&c\\b^*&c^*&0
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{matrix}\right]
=(a+a^*)xy+(b+b^*)zx+(c+c^*)yz$

However, no matter how hard I looked, there were no texts or Internet sites that mentioned pure imaginary numbers as conditions.

What did I think wrong?

Comment: This is true assuming that $|a\rangle$ is one of the orthonormal basis vectors in which $H$ has no diagonal components. In your example, it would be true only if $|a\rangle$ is $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ or $(0,0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perturbing Hamiltonian $H'$ is an operator which has different matrix representations depending on which orthonormal basis (ONB) you choose. If you choose an ONB set for which the elements are $\{| a_i\rangle\}$, then **in that basis** the matrix representation of H has zero diagonal components iff $\langle a_i|H'|a_i\rangle=0$.

This follows from the fact that $H'$ can be written as $$\displaystyle H'=\sum_{i,j}\langle a_i|H|a_j\rangle|a_i\rangle\langle a_j|.$$ The matrix element $H'_{a_i,a_j}\equiv \langle a_i|H|a_j\rangle$ is the $i$th row and $j$th column element if you choose to represent $H'$ as a matrix **in that specific basis.**

Comment: I can see that the condition that the eigenvector should be the basis of perturbation is necessary. But I don't know why such a condition suddenly appeared. I have never seen in a textbook that such conditions are necessary. (Griffiths, Quantum mechanics 3rd) Isn't the content not provided in the undergraduate cources? Or is it just that I didn't see it?

Comment: It is always there under the hood. Abstract vectors (and operators) live in abstract Hilbert spaces. When you write them down as vectors (and matrices), you have immediately implicitly chosen a basis.

Answer (score 2):

the vectors in the equation are not general vectors but orthonormal basis, in 11.1.16 they refer to the two basis of a two state system.

Comment: I think about two vectors

$\left|a\right>=\left[\begin{matrix}1/\sqrt2\\1/\sqrt2\\\end{matrix}\right], \left|b\right>=\left[\begin{matrix}1/\sqrt2\\-1/\sqrt2\\\end{matrix}\right]$

and perturbation

$H'=\left[\begin{matrix}0&c\\c^*&0\\\end{matrix}\right]$

$\left<a\middle|b\right>=0, \left<a\middle|a\right>=1$

Then $\left|a\right>, \left|b\right>$ are orthonormal

But still

$\left<a\middle|H'\middle|a\right>\neq0, \left<b\middle|H'\middle|b\right>\neq0$

Comment: Your $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ are not the basis vectors of the basis in which you wrote $H'$, that's why it doesn't work. The basis vectors in the basis you wrote $H'$ in are $|a'\rangle = (1, 0)$ and $|b'\rangle = (0, 1)$. That's always the case for a basis, that the basis vectors *in that basis* have a single 1 and the rest zeroes in their vector representation (by definition).